Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\{x+iy\mid x>0\lor(x=0\land y\geq0)\}$, $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$.

a) Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\{x+iy\mid x>0\lor(x=0\land y\geq0)\}$, $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$. Solve the equation $z^2=-1-\sqrt3i$ and find $f(-1-\sqrt3i)$.

My attempt: $|z|^2e^{i\alpha2}=2e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$, so $|z|=\sqrt{2}$ and $2\alpha=-\frac{2\pi}{3}+2k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $\alpha=-\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the solutions are $z_1=\sqrt2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}$ and $z_2=\sqrt2e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ or $z_1=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt6}{2}i$ and $z_2=-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt6}{2}i$. Everthing fine till now?
Then I notice $f(-1-\sqrt3i)=f(z^2)=\sqrt{z^2}$. And therefore $f(-1-\sqrt3i)=z_1=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt6}{2}i$.

b) Furthermore, let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}||z|>1\land(\frac{3\pi}{4}<arg(z)<\frac{5\pi}{4})\}$. I can imagine what $D$ looks like,
but have no idea how to find and describe $f(D)$.

c) Also, let $g:\mathbb{C}-\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\times(-\pi,\pi],g(z)=Log(z)$. I have to find out what $(g\circ f)(D)$ looks like.
Again, I know that $g(f(z))=g(\sqrt z)=Log(\sqrt z)$, but again any idea how to continue from here?


Main problem is that $D$ is infinite. Thanks for all your help!

Are you missing $i$ in the title?  Choose the root in the range

Looks like they want you to pick the answer in the range of the function $f$, i.e. $x>0$, i.e. $z_1$ and not $z_2$.

I expand my question now and add some more details. Please check

Your first part is correct, but using the conditions above, only $z_1$ will be the correct root, and thus $f(-1-i\sqrt{3}) = \sqrt {-1-i\sqrt{3}} = \sqrt {z}$.

Thanks for your comment. I edit my post now.

(a) Equation $z^2 = -1 - \sqrt{3}i$ can be written as $|z|^2e^{(2\alpha)i}=2e^{(-\frac{2\pi}{3})i}$, so $|z|=\sqrt{2}$ and $2\alpha=-\frac{2\pi}{3}+2k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But then $\alpha=-\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the solutions are $z_1=\sqrt2e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}}$ and $z_2=\sqrt2e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$ or $z_1=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt6}{2}i$ and $z_2=-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt6}{2}i$. From $\Re(z_1)>0$ and $\Re(z_2)<0$ it follows $f(-1 - \sqrt{3}i)=z_1=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt6}{2}i$.
(b) First, notice that $\sqrt z=\sqrt t e^{\frac{\alpha_0}{2}i},\alpha_0\in[\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi]$ and $\sqrt z=\sqrt t e^{(\frac{\alpha_0}{2}-\pi)i},\alpha_0\in[\pi,\frac{5\pi}{4}]$ when $z=te^{\alpha_0i},t>1,\alpha_0\in [\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}]$. So the solution is $\{z\in \mathbb{C}||z|>1\land(-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg z<-\frac{\pi}{8} \lor \frac{\pi}{8}<\arg z< \frac{\pi}{2})\}$.
(c) You need to find out where $g$ is mapping $f(D)$, so you should see that $\operatorname{Log} z=\ln |z|+i\operatorname{Arg} z = \ln \sqrt t+\frac{\alpha_0}{2}i$ for $z=\sqrt t e^{\frac{\alpha_0}{2}}, t>1, \alpha_0\in[\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi]$. So, from $t>1$ you should get $\ln \sqrt t>0$ and then $\mathbb{R}^+\times\{\frac{\alpha_0}{2}|\alpha_0\in[\frac{3\pi}{4},\pi]\}=\mathbb{R}^+\times[\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Similarly, you should get $\mathbb{R}^+\times[-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{3\pi}{8}]$, so the overall solution is $\mathbb{R}^+\times([-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{3\pi}{8}]\cup [\frac{3\pi}{8},\frac{\pi}{2}])$.
